# How do you determine which classical technique was used?

Tags: classical-cipher

For a class assignment we had to encrypt a message of at least 140 characters using only one of the classical cryptographic techniques. For extra credit we can decrypt someone else's message. I figure that the first step is finding out which method they used and go from there. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean by "classical cryptographic techniques"?

Comment: @Marcellus Sorry I guess I meant classical _ciphers_. These included Atbash, ROT13, Caesar, Affine, Rail-fence, Baconian, Polybius Square, Substitution, Columnar Transposition, Autokey, Beaufort, Porta, Running Key, Vigenere, Hill, Playfair, ADFGVX, Bifid, Straddle Checkerboard, Trifid, and Fractioned Morse. Sorry for the long list!

Comment: A bit of frequency analysis will give you a nice head start.

Comment: @Biv I've done a frequency analysis of each encrypted letter but I can't for the life of me figure out what to do with it.

Comment: So what did your frequency analysis tell you? Did it match the frequencies observed in the english language? If so, then something like ROT13 probably wasn't used. Why do you think that is? If it doesn't match the english language, you should be able to rule out some other ciphers.